# Structured Programming vs. Object Oriented Programming

Tags: object-oriented-analysis, structured-programming

In one class of my Structured programming course, the teacher told us that there are 3 way to decompose the problem to structured programming:

- Functional decomposition
- Algorithmic decomposition
- Object-oriented decomposition

As far as I know, object-oriented programming is different from structured programming, since OOP focuses on object, while SP focuses on tasks. However, because he said that we can use OO decomposition in order to analyze a problem, thus programming in a structured way, I start to get confused how I can do it. Moreover, if this is true, what are the differences that make these 2 concept distinct - Both paradigms use selection and repetition structures to implement functions, as well as both can be seen as a composition of objects? How does object-oriented decomposition relate to structured programming and object oriented programming?

I would be very appreciated for any explanation and example so that I can distinguish this clearly.

Comment: Structured programming just means you use structured control flow. Object orientation is a way of designing your abstractions. Nowadays, you rarely see anything that isn't structured programming (although, some edge cases like exception handling where it is violated).

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented programming is a subset of structured programming, as I understand.

So all object-oriented applications are also structural applications, but not all structural applications are object-oriented applications.